# Debugging multi-threaded application developed in C++ using Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, qt, debugging

My application runs as a windows service. 
It has thread pool - creates some threads.
All the created threads will be listening to TCP port for the input.
It also uses functions from DLLs inside the code.

Application is developed using Qt Library.

Right now we rely on logs for debugging. Need your inputs to make debugger working for this kind of application.

Comment: Usually services are written by such way, that it is possible to run them as Console applications (depending on command line parameters). This makes debugging easier. Of course, some things run different in a service and console application.

Comment: And, of course, https://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344 How to debug Windows services

Comment: @AlexFarber I dont think we have written in such a way to run it as console application.`code` class MyApplication : public QtService<QCoreApplication>{   } I am just setting the description of the service inside my constructor. Can i run this application as console application ?

Comment: Well, Windows services written from scratch are also not intended to run as console application. But some tricks allow to do this. Every service has some main function running in a loop. This function may be called directly, without starting a service and registering this function as service callback.

Comment: So, in the main function you can run some parts of internal code,  without calling service.exec. For example, port listening function. This usually allows to debug significant part of the code without running it as a service.

Comment: @AlexFarber ya i understand it's a work around i can debug to that level but once thread pool handed over to any thread i am not able to do that. I would like to debug my whole application. I am looking for concrete solution for this.